# 'Unable to load a Suite class' while running ScalaTest in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, akka

I'm having some issues today with running a simple TestKit test in Intellij.  The tests are for Scala code (I have the Scala plug-in for Intellij) and are based on [Ray Roestenburg's example](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/testkit-example.html).

The Intellij project was created using a "Maven Module" which I then added all the dependencies to and created my project.  The tests are located in the following place:

> ActorBlast/src/test/scala/basicTest.scala

I'm basically "right-clicking" on the test and selecting "Run".  What I get is the following error:

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7540...
>   Testing started at 2:29 PM ...
>   Unable to load a Suite class. This could be due to an error in your runpath.
>
> Missing class: BasicActorSpec java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   BasicActorSpec    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$35.apply(Runner.scala:2393)   at
>   org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$35.apply(Runner.scala:2391)   at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:264)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)  at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:263)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:105)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:2391)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1006)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1005)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:2659)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:1005)
>     at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:845)    at
>   org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)  at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2(ScalaTestRunner.java:144)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:35)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

I can't figure out what this means.  I've done a lot of searching but can't seem to find an answer. Note that the class the runner is complaining about not finding is the class I'm trying to test/run.  The basicTest.scala looks like this:

```
// Testing specific imports
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner
import org.scalatest.{ShouldMatchers, WordSpecLike, BeforeAndAfterAll}
import akka.testkit.{TestKit, DefaultTimeout, ImplicitSender}
// Actor specific imports
import akka.actor.{ActorRef, Actor, ActorSystem, Props}
// Misc. needed imports
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory


// In order to run tests in this module you need to use JUnitRunner (as per scalatest.org)
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class BasicActorSpec extends TestKit(ActorSystem("BasicActorSpec", ConfigFactory.parseString(BasicActorSpec.config)))
  with DefaultTimeout with ImplicitSender with WordSpecLike with ShouldMatchers with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  import BasicActorSpec._

  val echoRef = system.actorOf(Props[EchoActor])
  val forwardRef = system.actorOf(Props[ForwardActor])

  override def afterAll {
    shutdown(system)
  }


  /**
   * The actual tests...
   */
  "An EchoActor" should {
    "Respond with the same message it receives" in {
      within(500 millis) {
        echoRef ! "test"
        expectMsg("test")
      }
    }
  }

  "A Forwarding Actor" should {
    "Forward a message it receives" in {
      within(500 millis) {
        forwardRef ! "test"
        expectMsg("test")
      }
    }
  }

}

/**
 * Companion object of test class
 */
object BasicActorSpec {

  val config =
    """
      |akka {
      | loglevel = "Warning"
      |}
    """.stripMargin

  /**
   * Classes of Actors used in testing
   */
  class EchoActor extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case msg => sender ! msg
    }
  }

  class ForwardActor(next: ActorRef) extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case msg => next ! msg
    }
  }

}
```

Any help as to why I am getting this error would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 16):

Run build the project - It helped me to resolve that issue that could have happened to me when I cleared Cache IDEA :) while trying to tackle another issue

Comment: Just to be clear, I suppose AlexPes means build (ctrl+f9) from top menu, not the build in `edit configurations`. I did both build and rebuild just to be sure

Comment: for me it helped to actually clear the cache

Answer (score 11):

This is how I solved same exception:

```
--> Right click on your project folder in IDE:
```

[image]

```
--> Click Add Framework Support
--> Then Check Scala
--> Click OK
```

Comment: Thanks. I added `Play 2.0`, not `scala`

Comment: Check Scala - > No library selected -> can't click OK

Answer (score 8):

My project already had the setup as mentioned by @Rustam Aliyev. Still was getting the same exception. Rebuilding the project did not help either. Quite weird ; but Restarting the IDE helped to solve the issue

Comment: probably it should be the first thing to do with every issue with intelij

Answer (score 7):

This issue happened to me recently when I was trying to run tests in an inherited Scala project using *IntelliJ IDEA 2018 (Community Edition)*. Below steps helped me to fix it:

1. File → Project Structure → {Choose specific module} → "Paths" tab → Select "Use module compile output path" → Modify "*Test output path*" to point to *test-classes* folder. For example:

   > **Output path**: /home/rustam/IdeaProjects/{project}/{module}/target/scala-2.12/classes
   >   **Test output path**: /home/rustam/IdeaProjects/{project}/{module}/target/scala-2.12/test-classes
2. IntelliJ does not like multiple Scala classes defined in one file, so make sure the test class is named the same as the test file and nest other helper classes, which you can refactor later as necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Had two separate folders for IT and unit tests, and the test output path was pointing only to the IT tests., hence not finding classes for the unit tests!

Answer (score 7):

I met this issue when I used [Gatling](https://gatling.io/)

[image: I've replaced 'gatling-classes' to 'test-classes']

I fix it by replacing `gatling-classes` to `test-classes` on File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> *Module Name* -> Paths -> Test output path

Comment: That was the issue in my case. I am not sure if it is a bug or feature...

Comment: I had the same problem.  This change fixed it, so the code could run.  However, I now have a different problem:  The resources are not being copied.  Where do I go to fix that?

Comment: Fix for the resources not being copied:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513788/intellij-cant-find-classpath-test-resource

Answer (score 4):

You need to set up the Scala SDK. 
1.) Usually, intelliJ will ask you by showing a message on right hand corner of your editor
2.) You can do it by yourself as mentioned on the https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/discover-intellij-idea-for-scala.html

Comment: Please, do not put external links. At least, copy the relevant part to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was missing the Scala facet in my module.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2010/09/02/project-configuration-explained/

I got rid of the error once I configured module properly.

Comment: This solved it for me. It seems even now, IntelliJ won't prompt you for this until after you close and reopen your project once after creation.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to recompile the test classes:

```
sbt test:compile
```

Comment: This worked for me, run this then run the IntelliJ test, without having to do anything more, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using IntelliJ to run scalatest make sure the class paths are correct. For example:

```
 /dummyApp
```

your `build.sbt` should look like, `name := "dummyApp"`. If you name it `name := "dummy App"` you will get errors.

Answer (score 1):

Another one in the long list of checks, if you do not use unique test names you get this error without any hint, in a long test suite it is easier to miss.

Failed

```
test("Check thing 1") {
 class TestClass1 extends MainClass1{
 ... }
test("Check thing 1") {
 class TestClass2 extends MainClass2{
 ... }
```

Successful

```
test("Check thing 1") {
 class TestClass1 extends MainClass1{
 ... }
test("Check thing 2") {
 class TestClass2 extends MainClass2{
 ... }
```

Comment: You saved my day, thanks! I didn't expect this to work by looking at the error message. I think the error message can be improved since it is misleading or too general.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had in `Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> sbt`

`Use sbt shell for build and import` checkbox enabled

And the test was not in the expected directory `src/test` but in `src/it` (integrated test).

Comment: O, and how did you fix it? (I want to run the test with sbt and have it inside src/it)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the error when the test class was not part of any package.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the multi maven module and tried all possibilities here but not able to fix this. But for me ***I closed the complete IntelliJ -> removed .idea folder -> deleted managed projects from recent projects window.-> reimport the project*** did the job.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing keeps happening to me every now and then. All the more concrete suggestions above have merit. Another possibility (which worked this time for me): Edit the run configuration for your tests; click "Use sbt"; run the tests (this should have no problem since it's just using the sbt-shell to run the tests); now unselect "Use sbt" and try it. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same message on Idea 2021.1. I tried all the ways above but what helped me is running Scala-tests via sbt like this:

```
sbt "; project nameOfProject; testOnly some.package.SomeTest"
```

After that I could debug the same tests via Idea.

Answer (score 0):

I had two modules marked as Test Sources Root and thus it didn't like that. So I unmarked one and then it worked great

Answer (score 0):

I also met same issue. I just restarted IntelliJ and  rebuild project . then it was working well.

[image]