# Why getResource is NULL?

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, resources

it's not Android project , it's Java Library in Android Studio... File->New->New Module->Java Library

I try to get file from resources folder, but it is always NULL

```
    System.out.println("File is "+getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("google-services.json"));
    System.out.println("File is "+getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/google-services.json"));
    System.out.println("File is "+getClass().getResource("google-services.json"));
    System.out.println("File is "+getClass().getResource("/google-services.json"));
```

Result `File is null`

**Here is my structure:**

[image]
[image]
**Run config**
[image]

What is wrong? Why I can't get File **google-services.json** from res folder?

**UPDATE:** Seems resource folder is not added to `java/build/classes/main` folder

Because `System.out.println("File is "+getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(""));`

Result is `File is file:/D:/ProjectsHome/JavaFlat/java/build/classes/main/`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by adding resources folder to dependencies

Push F4-> Modules->YOUR_MODULE-> Dependencies ->Add "JARs or dirs"->Choose res folder->Classes
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39289902/2425851

Answer (score 0):

Created an account just to say this worked for me.

In IntelliJ, follow the steps:

File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies Tab -> + Sign -> JARs or directories -> select resources directory -> Classes