# File not found when located in "Test Resources Root"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, resource-files

I am new to IntelliJ IDEA and I am trying to use specific files for my unit tests, but it seems that these cannot be found. I have built a special project/module to "reduce" the error in a totally clean setting to make sure that I don't miss something, however, it still does not work.

My file structure (as shown in the screenshot):
.../test/jave/FooTest.java
.../test/resources/test.txt

Folder ".../test/resources" has been marked as "Test Resources Root". However, when the test runs, file could not be found.

[image: Screenshot of error when running test in a reduced program]

I suppose that marking the folder as "Test Resources Root" should add all its files in the path. Isn't this right?

PS. I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513788/intellij-cant-find-classpath-test-resource) but even adding the folder as a dependency did not work.

Answer (score 0):

To get a file from the resources folder, You can use any approach given here:https://www.baeldung.com/junit-src-test-resources-directory-path

```
File("test.txt").exists();
```

Will return true when your file located at ...\project_name\test.txt.
Check by

```
File("test.txt").getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the guidance. However, I am still wondering, if marking the folder as "Test Resources Root" does not add it to my path, then what is the point of marking it? Am I missing something?

Comment: I never use IntelliJ IDEA so I don't know what it will do when we mark Test Resources Root. Does it add <testResources> set up in pom file? I used eclipse.