# Unable to run integration test in Intellij Idea for scala project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, integration-testing

I am using the following version of Intellij Idea

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-191.7479.19, built on May 28, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b58 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.13.6
```

I have imported an sbt project and am able to run unit test cases successfully. However, as soon as I run the test suite containing integration test cases, I get the following error

```
Testing started at 14:57 ...
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=53306:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/IdeaIC2019.1/Scala/lib/runners.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/sampleProject/hive/server/target/scala-2.12/test-classes:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/sampleProject/hive/server/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/sampleProject/common/queue/target/scala-2.12/test-classes:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/sampleProject/common/queue/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/sampleProject/common/event/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/sampleProject/common/test/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/sampleProject/edr/events/target/scala-2.12/test-classes:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/sampleProject/edr/events/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/sampleProject/hive/api/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/sampleProject/hive/dao/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/sampleProject/hive/events/target/scala-2.12/test-classes:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/sampleProject/hive/events/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/sampleProject/mailer/flows/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/sampleProject/mailer/templates/.jvm/target/scala-2.12/test-classes:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/sampleProject/mailer/templates/.jvm/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/sampleProject/payments/data/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/sampleProject/tenants/data/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/sampleProject/mailer/mandrill-api/target/scala-2.12/test-classes:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/sampleProject/mailer/mandrill-api/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/sampleProject/monitor/events/target/scala-2.12/test-classes:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/sampleProject/monitor/events/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/sampleProject/scoring/events/target/scala-2.12/test-classes:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/sampleProject/scoring/events/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/jars/logback-core-1.2.3.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/jars/aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.342.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/jars/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.285.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ec2/jars/aws-java-sdk-ec2-1.11.285.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-emr/jars/aws-java-sdk-emr-1.11.285.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-iam/jars/aws-java-sdk-iam-1.11.285.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-kinesis/jars/aws-java-sdk-kinesis-1.11.342.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-kms/jars/aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.285.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-redshift/jars/aws-java-sdk-redshift-1.11.285.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3/jars/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.285.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-simpledb/jars/aws-java-sdk-simpledb-1.11.285.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-sns/jars/aws-java-sdk-sns-1.11.342.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-sqs/jars/aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.11.342.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-stepfunctions/jars/aws-java-sdk-stepfunctions-1.11.285.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-sts/jars/aws-java-sdk-sts-1.11.342.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/jmespath-java/jars/jmespath-java-1.11.342.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.chuusai/shapeless_2.12/bundles/shapeless_2.12-2.3.3.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/bundles/jackson-annotations-2.9.8.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/bundles/jackson-core-2.9.8.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/bundles/jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-cbor/bundles/jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.9.8.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml/bundles/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.9.6.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-guava/bundles/jackson-datatype-guava-2.9.4.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/bundles/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.8.11.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/bundles/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.8.11.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-base/bundles/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.9.4.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/bundles/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.9.4.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/bundles/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.9.4.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-paranamer/bundles/jackson-module-paranamer-2.9.8.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-scala_2.12/bundles/jackson-module-scala_2.12-2.9.8.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.uuid/java-uuid-generator/bundles/java-uuid-generator-3.1.5.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.jnr/jffi/jars/jffi-1.2.15.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.jnr/jffi/jars/jffi-1.2.15-native.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.jnr/jnr-constants/jars/jnr-constants-0.9.8.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.jnr/jnr-enxio/jars/jnr-enxio-0.16.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.jnr/jnr-ffi/jars/jnr-ffi-2.1.4.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.jnr/jnr-posix/jars/jnr-posix-3.0.35.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.jnr/jnr-unixsocket/jars/jnr-unixsocket-0.18.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.jnr/jnr-x86asm/jars/jnr-x86asm-1.0.2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.julien-truffaut/monocle-core_2.12/jars/monocle-core_2.12-1.4.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.seratch/awscala-core_2.12/jars/awscala-core_2.12-0.7.2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.seratch/awscala-dynamodb_2.12/jars/awscala-dynamodb_2.12-0.7.2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.seratch/awscala-ec2_2.12/jars/awscala-ec2_2.12-0.7.2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.seratch/awscala-emr_2.12/jars/awscala-emr_2.12-0.7.2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.seratch/awscala-iam_2.12/jars/awscala-iam_2.12-0.7.2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.seratch/awscala-redshift_2.12/jars/awscala-redshift_2.12-0.7.2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.seratch/awscala-s3_2.12/jars/awscala-s3_2.12-0.7.2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.seratch/awscala-simpledb_2.12/jars/awscala-simpledb_2.12-0.7.2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.seratch/awscala-sqs_2.12/jars/awscala-sqs_2.12-0.7.2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.seratch/awscala-stepfunctions_2.12/jars/awscala-stepfunctions_2.12-0.7.2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.seratch/awscala-sts_2.12/jars/awscala-sts_2.12-0.7.2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.seratch/awscala_2.12/jars/awscala_2.12-0.7.2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.swagger-akka-http/swagger-akka-http_2.12/jars/swagger-akka-http_2.12-0.14.1.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.tminglei/slick-pg_2.12/jars/slick-pg_2.12-0.16.3.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.tminglei/slick-pg_circe-json_2.12/jars/slick-pg_circe-json_2.12-0.16.3.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.tminglei/slick-pg_core_2.12/jars/slick-pg_core_2.12-0.16.3.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.virtuald/curvesapi/jars/curvesapi-1.04.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.google.api-client/google-api-client/jars/google-api-client-1.23.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.google.apis/google-api-services-safebrowsing/jars/google-api-services-safebrowsing-v4-rev44-1.23.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/jars/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/jars/jsr305-3.0.1.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.google.guava/guava/bundles/guava-20.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.google.http-client/google-http-client/jars/google-http-client-1.23.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.google.http-client/google-http-client-jackson2/jars/google-http-client-jackson2-1.23.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client/jars/google-oauth-client-1.23.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.iheart/ficus_2.12/jars/ficus_2.12-1.4.3.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.itextpdf/itextpdf/jars/itextpdf-5.5.11.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.lightbend.akka/akka-stream-alpakka-csv_2.12/jars/akka-stream-alpakka-csv_2.12-0.20.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.lightbend.akka/akka-stream-alpakka-kinesis_2.12/jars/akka-stream-alpakka-kinesis_2.12-0.20.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.lightbend.akka/akka-stream-alpakka-s3_2.12/jars/akka-stream-alpakka-s3_2.12-0.20.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.lightbend.akka/akka-stream-alpakka-sqs_2.12/jars/akka-stream-alpakka-sqs_2.12-0.20.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.mandrillapp.wrapper.lutung/lutung/jars/lutung-0.0.8.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.nrinaudo/kantan.codecs-cats_2.12/jars/kantan.codecs-cats_2.12-0.4.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.nrinaudo/kantan.codecs-shapeless_2.12/jars/kantan.codecs-shapeless_2.12-0.4.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.nrinaudo/kantan.codecs_2.12/jars/kantan.codecs_2.12-0.4.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.nrinaudo/kantan.csv-cats_2.12/jars/kantan.csv-cats_2.12-0.4.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.nrinaudo/kantan.csv-generic_2.12/jars/kantan.csv-generic_2.12-0.4.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.nrinaudo/kantan.csv_2.12/jars/kantan.csv_2.12-0.4.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.osinka.i18n/scala-i18n_2.12/jars/scala-i18n_2.12-1.0.2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.pauldijou/jwt-circe_2.12/jars/jwt-circe_2.12-0.16.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.pauldijou/jwt-core-impl_2.12/jars/jwt-core-impl_2.12-0.16.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.pauldijou/jwt-core_2.12/jars/jwt-core_2.12-0.16.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.pauldijou/jwt-json-common_2.12/jars/jwt-json-common_2.12-0.16.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.spotify/docker-client/jars/docker-client-8.11.5.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.sun.mail/javax.mail/jars/javax.mail-1.6.1.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.thoughtworks.paranamer/paranamer/bundles/paranamer-2.8.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe/config/bundles/config-1.3.3.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe/ssl-config-core_2.12/bundles/ssl-config-core_2.12-0.3.6.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.12/jars/akka-actor_2.12-2.5.19.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-http-core_2.12/jars/akka-http-core_2.12-10.1.7.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-http-testkit_2.12/jars/akka-http-testkit_2.12-10.1.7.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-http-xml_2.12/jars/akka-http-xml_2.12-10.1.7.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-http_2.12/jars/akka-http_2.12-10.1.7.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-parsing_2.12/jars/akka-parsing_2.12-10.1.7.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-protobuf_2.12/jars/akka-protobuf_2.12-2.5.19.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-slf4j_2.12/jars/akka-slf4j_2.12-2.5.19.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-stream-testkit_2.12/jars/akka-stream-testkit_2.12-2.5.19.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-stream_2.12/jars/akka-stream_2.12-2.5.19.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-testkit_2.12/jars/akka-testkit_2.12-2.5.19.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-functional_2.12/jars/play-functional_2.12-2.6.12.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-json_2.12/jars/play-json_2.12-2.6.12.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.slick/slick-hikaricp_2.12/bundles/slick-hikaricp_2.12-3.2.3.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.slick/slick_2.12/bundles/slick_2.12-3.2.3.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.whisk/docker-testkit-core_2.12/jars/docker-testkit-core_2.12-0.9.8.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.whisk/docker-testkit-impl-spotify_2.12/jars/docker-testkit-impl-spotify_2.12-0.9.8.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.whisk/docker-testkit-scalatest_2.12/jars/docker-testkit-scalatest_2.12-0.9.8.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/bundles/HikariCP-2.5.1.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/commons-codec/commons-codec/jars/commons-codec-1.10.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/commons-io/commons-io/jars/commons-io-2.6.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/commons-lang/commons-lang/jars/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/commons-logging/commons-logging/jars/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/de.heikoseeberger/akka-http-circe_2.12/jars/akka-http-circe_2.12-1.21.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/io.circe/circe-core_2.12/jars/circe-core_2.12-0.9.3.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/io.circe/circe-generic-extras_2.12/jars/circe-generic-extras_2.12-0.9.3.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/io.circe/circe-generic_2.12/jars/circe-generic_2.12-0.9.3.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/io.circe/circe-java8_2.12/jars/circe-java8_2.12-0.9.3.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/io.circe/circe-jawn_2.12/jars/circe-jawn_2.12-0.9.3.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/io.circe/circe-numbers_2.12/jars/circe-numbers_2.12-0.9.3.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/io.circe/circe-optics_2.12/jars/circe-optics_2.12-0.9.3.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/io.circe/circe-parser_2.12/jars/circe-parser_2.12-0.9.3.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/io.github.nremond/pbkdf2-scala_2.12/jars/pbkdf2-scala_2.12-0.6.3.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/io.sentry/sentry/jars/sentry-1.7.5.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/io.sentry/sentry-logback/jars/sentry-logback-1.7.5.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/io.swagger/swagger-annotations/bundles/swagger-annotations-1.5.20.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/io.swagger/swagger-core/jars/swagger-core-1.5.20.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/io.swagger/swagger-jaxrs/bundles/swagger-jaxrs-1.5.20.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/io.swagger/swagger-models/bundles/swagger-models-1.5.20.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/javax.activation/activation/jars/activation-1.1.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api/jars/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/javax.validation/validation-api/jars/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/jars/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api/jars/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/joda-time/joda-time/jars/joda-time-2.9.9.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/jars/byte-buddy-1.7.9.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy-agent/jars/byte-buddy-agent-1.7.9.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/net.sf.jtidy/jtidy/jars/jtidy-r938.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.commons/commons-compress/jars/commons-compress-1.9.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/jars/commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/jars/httpclient-4.5.5.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/jars/httpcore-4.4.9.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/jars/log4j-to-slf4j-2.2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.poi/poi/jars/poi-3.15-beta2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/jars/poi-ooxml-3.15-beta2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/jars/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15-beta2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/jars/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/jars/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.57.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/jars/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.59.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/jars/bcprov-jdk15on-1.57.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/jars/bcprov-jdk15on-1.59.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.flywaydb/flyway-core/jars/flyway-core-4.2.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-api/jars/hk2-api-2.4.0-b34.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-locator/jars/hk2-locator-2.4.0-b34.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-utils/jars/hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.glassfish.hk2/osgi-resource-locator/jars/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.glassfish.hk2.external/aopalliance-repackaged/jars/aopalliance-repackaged-2.4.0-b34.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.glassfish.hk2.external/javax.inject/jars/javax.inject-2.4.0-b34.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged/jersey-guava/bundles/jersey-guava-2.22.2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.glassfish.jersey.connectors/jersey-apache-connector/jars/jersey-apache-connector-2.22.2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client/jars/jersey-client-2.22.2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common/jars/jersey-common-2.22.2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.glassfish.jersey.ext/jersey-entity-filtering/jars/jersey-entity-filtering-2.22.2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson/jars/jersey-media-json-jackson-2.22.2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.javassist/javassist/bundles/javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.joda/joda-convert/jars/joda-convert-2.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.mockito/mockito-core/jars/mockito-core-2.13.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.objenesis/objenesis/jars/objenesis-2.6.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.ow2.asm/asm/jars/asm-5.0.3.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.ow2.asm/asm-analysis/jars/asm-analysis-5.0.3.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.ow2.asm/asm-commons/jars/asm-commons-5.0.3.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.ow2.asm/asm-tree/jars/asm-tree-5.0.3.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.ow2.asm/asm-util/jars/asm-util-5.0.3.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.postgresql/postgresql/bundles/postgresql-42.2.5.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.reactivestreams/reactive-streams/jars/reactive-streams-1.0.2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.reflections/reflections/jars/reflections-0.9.11.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.12.8.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.12.8.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/jars/scala-reflect-2.12.8.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-java8-compat_2.12/bundles/scala-java8-compat_2.12-0.8.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.12/bundles/scala-parser-combinators_2.12-1.1.1.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-xml_2.12/bundles/scala-xml_2.12-1.1.1.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.scalactic/scalactic_2.12/bundles/scalactic_2.12-3.0.5.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.scalamock/scalamock-core_2.12/jars/scalamock-core_2.12-3.6.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.scalamock/scalamock-scalatest-support_2.12/jars/scalamock-scalatest-support_2.12-3.6.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.12/bundles/scalatest_2.12-3.0.5.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.scalatra.scalate/scalate-core_2.12/jars/scalate-core_2.12-1.8.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.scalatra.scalate/scalate-util_2.12/jars/scalate-util_2.12-1.8.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.scalaz/scalaz-core_2.12/bundles/scalaz-core_2.12-7.2.8.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.scaldi/scaldi_2.12/jars/scaldi_2.12-0.5.8.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.scommons.service/scommons-service-dao_2.12/jars/scommons-service-dao_2.12-0.1.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/jars/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/jars/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/jars/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.spire-math/imp_2.12/jars/imp_2.12-0.3.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.spire-math/jawn-parser_2.12/jars/jawn-parser_2.12-0.11.1.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.typelevel/cats-core_2.12/jars/cats-core_2.12-1.1.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.typelevel/cats-kernel_2.12/jars/cats-kernel_2.12-1.1.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.typelevel/cats-macros_2.12/jars/cats-macros_2.12-1.1.0.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.typelevel/machinist_2.12/jars/machinist_2.12-0.6.2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.typelevel/macro-compat_2.12/jars/macro-compat_2.12-1.1.1.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.webjars/swagger-ui/jars/swagger-ui-2.2.6.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.webjars/webjars-locator-core/jars/webjars-locator-core-0.35.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.xhtmlrenderer/flying-saucer-core/jars/flying-saucer-core-9.1.13.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.xhtmlrenderer/flying-saucer-pdf-itext5/jars/flying-saucer-pdf-itext5-9.1.13.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.yaml/snakeyaml/bundles/snakeyaml-1.18.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/software.amazon.ion/ion-java/bundles/ion-java-1.0.2.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/stax/stax-api/jars/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.google.code.gson/gson/jars/gson-2.8.5.jar:/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/com.stripe/stripe-java/jars/stripe-java-10.14.0.jar" org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner -s hive.test.AllIntegrationTests -C org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestReporter -showProgressMessages true

Unable to load a Suite class. This could be due to an error in your runpath. Missing class: hive.test.AllIntegrationTests
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hive.test.AllIntegrationTests
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$6(Runner.scala:1213)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$6$adapted(Runner.scala:1211)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$filterImpl$1(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:250)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filterImpl$(TraversableLike.scala:248)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filterImpl(Traversable.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filter(TraversableLike.scala:262)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filter$(TraversableLike.scala:262)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1211)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24(Runner.scala:1031)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24$adapted(Runner.scala:1010)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1506)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:1010)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:850)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2(ScalaTestRunner.java:131)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:28)


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I followed this post on SO (['Unable to load a Suite class' while running ScalaTest in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838012/unable-to-load-a-suite-class-while-running-scalatest-in-intellij)) and systematically tried all the suggestions provided by people.

By the way those same tests run successfully when I run them using the command line using the command

```
sbt -mem 2048 "project projectName" test it:test
```

However, I was not able to resolve the issue. I also tried downgrading the Intellij version as well as Java version as the last resort, but did not find any luck. Any pointers to solve my current problem will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: @RohdeFischer Yes I am able to run IT tests using command sbt -mem 2048 "project projectName" test it:test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had installed two plugins in Intellij

1. Scala plugin by Jetbrains
2. SBT plugin by some 3rd party

Removing the SBT plugin enabled me to run the integration test cases from Intellij again.

Answer (score 3):

First make sure it works when running `sbt it:test` or if you use sub-modules `sbt module/it:test`

If it doesn't sbt has this great resource: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing.html#Integration+Tests

As a template for a working setup, a `build.sbt`:

```scala
ThisBuild / name := "project"
ThisBuild / organization := "dk.rohdef.project"
ThisBuild / version := "0.1"
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.0"


lazy val IntTest = IntegrationTest extend(Test)

lazy val root = project
    .in(file("."))
    .configs(IntTest)
    .settings(
      Defaults.itSettings
    )
```

Be aware that if you run sub-projects/modules it seems that you need to set configs and settings for each module.

The integration tests should be located in `src/it/scala` - and yes abbreviating integration tests to `it` is bad, but it seems to be the de-facto standard :(

Then close IntelliJ, and delete `.idea` from your project folder (or take a backup if paranoid). Open you project again, and import it from sbt. I only check "Library sources" and "Allow overriding sbt version", but it should work no matter what configuration you use.

**Other things to try**

- Reload the sbt settings in IntelliJ
- `File` -> `Invalidate Caches/Restart`
- Check settings in `File` -> `Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `sbt` (including that the right Java version is used, from experience 1.8 seems to be a good choice)
- Check that the right Java version is used in `File` -> `Project Settings` -> `Project`
- If nothing else works, try to run with clean settings, rename or delete your settings folder in the location specified by: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-project-and-ide-settings.html#restore-defaults

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but however, this does not solve my problem. My build.sbt file is similar to yours, however I cant share it as it is client code. I tried refreshing the project, deleting the .idea folder couple of times and this does not work for me

Comment: The same code works in my colleagues system and he is able to run it test from intellij. I have only two plugins in intellij idea Scala and Sbt

Comment: This is one thing that is different in our systems, I could not download JDK from oracle website and had to settle for OpenJDK, however, my colleague had downloaded it long time ago and has the oracle 1.8 JDK. As you mentioned I went into Settings then Build, Execution, Deployment -> sbt and found JRE version to be Default (1.8 - project SDK)

Comment: Hmm, OpenJDK works fine for me, on a Linux system though. Could you try to rename the settings-folder for IntelliJ, so you run on the default settings?

Comment: How do you rename settings folder ?

Comment: You can find where your default folder is located here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-project-and-ide-settings.html#restore-defaults

Comment: FYI, added the solution suggestions so far to the answer, and removed the comments concerning them :)